# Define injective function and prove by giving an example.

Tags: functional-analysis

Answer: A function is injective if and only if whenever $f(x)=f(y)$, $x=y$; for all $x,y \in \text{dom}(f)$

my question can someone provide an example proving the above definition that $f(x)=f(y),\ x=y$.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is the most obvious injective function I have in mind. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x$.

It is directly implied that
$$f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$$

Answer (score 1):

Any function which would strictly increase or decrease like $$f(x)=-x$$ or $$f(x)=|x|$$ in interval $(0,\infty)$

Comment: what if f: R $\to$ R defined by f(x)=x^2, is this injective?

Comment: No its not because $f(-1)=f(1)$ so from the deinition its not injective, however in $(a,\infty)$ where $a \ge 0$ it is.

Answer (score 1):

Take the empty function $\emptyset\to\emptyset$.